# Snowflake module error: DDL load failed: The specified module could not be foud

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

currently, I'm trying to execute a python code that extracts information from the snowflake.
When I running my code in my PC executed well, but if I try to run the code in a VM It shows me this error:
[image]

The VM is new, and I just have executed these commands:

-pip install virtualenv
(inside of the env)

-pip install snowflake-connector-python[pandas]

-pip install azure.eventhub (I need this package)

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pandas python library requires some extra native libraries (DLLs) to load certain submodules due to use of C-extensions.

Very recent Pandas versions, after 1.0.1, [are facing a build distribution issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/32857) currently, where their published packages are not carrying the necessary Microsoft Visual C++ redistributed DLL files to allow these modules to load.

You can try to get around this issue in two ways:

[Install the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable package](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads) in your Windows VM directly, so that their DLLs appear for Pandas to load dynamically.

Or, switch to using a slightly older release of Pandas (1.0.1) [which distributed the necessary DLLs properly](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/21321), until they resolve the issue with their binary packaging in future:

```vb
C:\> pip install pandas==1.0.1 snowflake-connector-python
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to have the [Snowflake Python Connector prerequisites](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-install.html#prerequisites) installed.

You can try the following commands:

```
// Install Python
sudo yum install python36

// Install pip
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py

// Install Snowflake Connector
sudo yum install -y libffi-devel openssl-devel;
pip install --upgrade snowflake-connector-python;
```